# Using both the Authorization header and cookies in authentication?

Tags: authentication, cookies, local-storage, token, xss

Why is it not more common to use cookies as *implicit* authentication session handling? I'm new to web development, but I've seen the following pattern:

```
1. Authenticate with backend
2. Backend sends cookie-based auth token _and_ provides the token in the response body
3. Subsequent requests expect cookie (browser implicit) + authorization header (user explicit)
```

While this works, what is the purpose of providing the tokens in both the response headers (i.e. cookies) *and* in the body? If the cookies are made `HttpOnly`, which they seem to often rightfully be, then they cannot be later retrieved by your JS-based frontend. This implies a need for storing the tokens client-side in some way. And the public opinion on whether or not authentication tokens should be stored in e.g. `LocalStorage` seems rather divided.

And if you want persistent sessions you need to use it .. or perhaps make use of a `/whoami` endpoint that parses the cookie only and returns an auth/refresh token (?) on first render of the frontend.

---

What is the motivation for requiring `Authorization` headers alongside cookies that inherently contain the same information?

Is it just that an XSS attacker would need both components for a successful attack (browser-based cookie + authorization header)? Namely, somewhat akin to 2FA.

e.g. applications can be made less vulnerable to XSS attacks if clients, for instance, store their auth tokens [in memory](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage#browser-in-memory-scenarios) (since XSS attacks can read LocalStorage anyway).